# Bar plot not visible in ggplot when plotted

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 dataframes. I reshape them and want to achieve a grouped barplot of the "Fixed", "Transient" and "Production" from 1981-2015. I plot through ggplot2. However in the plotting code of ggplot, there are no bars shown. I notice the scale change, but no bars are shown of any 3 categories (fixed, transient and production).

what is the source of the error?

```
Years<-c('1981', '1982', '1983', '1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989','1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015')
Fixed<-c(0.001297,0.001329,0.001361,0.001256,0.001196,0.001251,
0.001256,0.00124,0.001255,0.001263,0.001234,0.001281,0.001243,
0.001278,0.001338,0.001361,0.00141,0.001361,0.001306,0.001224,
0.001228,0.001254,0.001319,0.001337,0.001383,0.001419,
0.001444,0.001433,0.001422,0.001463,0.001487,0.00148,
0.001094,0.001042,0.00108)




Transient <- c(0.001297,0.001329,0.001361,0.001256,0.001196,0.001251,0.001256,0.00124,0.001255,0.001263,
0.001234,0.001281,0.001243,0.001278,0.001338,0.001361,0.00141,0.001361,0.001361,0.00124,
0.001228,0.001254,0.001319,0.001337,0.001383,0.001419,0.001444,0.001433,0.001422,0.001463,
0.001487,0.00148,0.001094,0.001042,0.00108)


Production<-c(0.0125,0.0128,0.0128,0.0128,0.0127,0.0132,0.0123,0.0133,0.0135,
0.0135,0.0132,0.0138,0.0135,0.0141,0.0137,0.0142,0.0281,0.0322,0.0295,0.0295,
0.0276,0.0294,0.0304,0.0339,0.0345,0.0367,0.0348,0.0398,0.0385,0.0388,0.039,0.0391,
0.0434,0.0425,0.0434)



df <- data.frame(Years,Fixed,Transient, Production)

df.m<-reshape2::melt(df)
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00","#56B4E9")

df.m %>%

ggplot(aes(x = factor(Years,levels=c('1981', '1982', '1983', '1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989','1990','1991','1992','1993','1994','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015')), y = value, fill = variable))+
scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Fixed", "Production"),values=cbPalette )+
theme_bw()+
theme(legend.text=element_text(size=15),axis.text.y=element_text(size=15),
axis.text.x=element_text(size=12.80),axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12.20),
axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15))+theme(legend.title =element_blank())+
labs(y= "Production", x = "Years")
```

Comment: Forgot `geom_bar` or `geom_col`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no bars layer to be drawn. The following code fixes it.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Years, Fixed, Transient, Production)

df.m <- reshape2::melt(df)
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00","#56B4E9")

ggplot(df.m, aes(x = factor(Years), y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Fixed", "Transient", "Production"), values = cbPalette) +
  labs(y = "Production", x = "Years") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(size=15),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=15),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=12.80, angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12.20),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
    legend.title = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]